# Count max value where substring = substring-?

Tags: php, html, substring

I have a table in a string where the string could contain this string (`$table_data`):

```
<table>
<tr class="rowset-1"><td>cell1</td></tr>
<tr class="rowset-2"><td>cell1</td></tr>
<tr class="rowset-3"><td>cell1</td></tr>
</table>
```

From this string I want to count how many rows there are in the table. I do count number of rows like this:

```
$i = 1;
while( true )
{
    if (strpos( $table_data, 'rowset-'.$i ) === false ) 
    {
        $nr_rows = $i - 1;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

What I'm doing is simply to look for the class rowset-X were x is a number starting with 1. If it does not exist I have counted number of rows...  (In above case 3 rows)

I'm looking for a way just to get largest number of rowset-? in a string (where ? is the largest number) with a better approach **(My gut feeling is that my current approach is absolutely not the best).**

Comment: You're storing HTML in a string, so it's going to get messer faster than if you had say a 3D array. Any way to get the data as an array or is it given as a string? In a sense, you could parse it into an array from the HTML if you are going to continue manipulating it for easier mangagment.

Comment: Are these rowsets always in order from smallest to largest?

Comment: @Jack - It's stored in a string for fast access of viewing the table.

Comment: @Remy - yes it's always from smallest to largest

Comment: You could perhaps use [strrpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and substring to extract the last rowset part and get that number, maybe that would suffice?

Comment: @Remy - good thought. Actually I just realised (silly me) that I just could count number of rows by counting substring of rowset-

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you need to tell the world how stupid you are until you realise what you should do about it ;-)

I realised I could use `substr_count` to achieve what I want.

```
$table_data = '
<table>
<tr class="rowset-1"><td class="colset-1">cell1</td><td class="colset-2">cell1</td></tr>
<tr class="rowset-2"><td class="colset-1">cell1</td><td class="colset-2">cell1</td></tr>
<tr class="rowset-3"><td class="colset-1">cell1</td><td class="colset-2">cell1</td></tr>
</table>';

//Search rowset-1,2,3 etc... to return number of rows
//Search colset-1,2,3 etc... to return number of cols
//or actually.. don't care about 1,2,3 - just get number of rows and nr of cols!
//
$nr_rows = substr_count( $table_data, 'rowset-');
$nr_cols = floor( substr_count( $table_data, 'colset-') / $nr_rows );
```